# how to save text in app_resource. asp net mvc c# metatags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, asp.net-mvc-views, metatag

I have all my text inside view coding.  I preffer to save it in app_resources, because i would to add other languages in future, and its look quite cleaner.

I just know that I need to use metatags in my view for text to connect it with file app_resource. How to it correctly, could you show me some examples how it looks like in view??

Thanks a lot and take care,
Ragims

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to create App_LocalResources folder in the same folder where you hold your views. Then give a name to **zzz.resx**. And then you can call resources in your view via **zzz**.

Example: *You have folder Contact in your View Folder.
Your add App_LocalResources to Contact folder. Then you give a name Contact.resx to your *.resx file.*

Finally in the view you can use `<%= ContactResources.Contact.Index_ContactWithUs %>` where Contact.Index_ContactWithUs - name of concrete resource.

Don't forget that in resources settings you can modify access type (Internal or Public).